# Execute jar file before tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, testing, junit

I have a jar file with a small program, when i execute this file spring server runs.
I need to write some automation tests for this program.

So, my question is how to execute this file.jar automatically before test? (My goal is to run server automatically)
or if there are any other better ways to write automation test for this file.jar i would like to know that

```
@Before
public void before() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/chromedriver/chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using? In IntelliJ IDEA it is quite simple to add or chain together custom run configurations.

Comment: @nylanderdev yes, it's IDEA

Comment: By using the "edit configurations" option (situated between "build" and "run") you can add steps that will execute "before launch" of a configuration.

Comment: May be you know how to make this with maven?

Comment: Use "Edit configurations" and create a new config. Pick "maven" as your template, and then add the things you want to do to the "before launch" list. Don't forget to pick a maven phase or goal too.